# Window manager Service doubts in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new to Android frame work and i am understanding Android Display System.

I have some questions about android window system,

As my understanding each window have one or more surfaces and each surface have one or more views or view groups.These views can be drawn on to surface back buffer  using Canvas.
and Surface flinger will flip the buffers when back buffer is full
and my doubts are

Does one activity have one window  or one application have one window?

Buffer size for every surface have same size or different size ?
if buffer size is different for different surface who will provide the size of the buffer and also window size?

How Surface Flinger will use 8MB memory ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I can answer"Does one activity have one window or one application have one window?“

1)one activity can have one or more window,including STARTING_WINDOW,SUB_WINDOW,etc,
2)application not related window directly,activity does,so it is decided by activity's number.